# I set two ints equal to each other but I still get: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am trying out basic problems to help me learn and practice the basics. Here is the problem:

Given a list of stock prices (daily). Returns the best profit with consideration to the order of the stock prices in the list. (Sell price has be after buy price in the list) Code below:

```
stock_prices = [12, 7, 5, 8, 11, 14]

i = 0
j = 1

buy = min(stock_prices)
sell = max(stock_prices)

def get_max_profit(stock_prices):
    for stock_prices in stock_prices:
        if stock_prices[i] == buy:
            return print("Buy Price:", stock_prices[i], "Sell Price:", max(stock_prices[i:]),
                         "Profit:", max(stock_prices[i:]) - stock_prices[i])
        elif stock_prices[i] > stock_prices[j]:
            return i + 1, j + 1
        elif stock_prices[j] > stock_prices[i] and (stock_prices[i:] != buy and stock_prices[i:] > stock_prices[i]):
            return print("Buy Price:", stock_prices[i], "Sell Price:", max(stock_prices[i:]),
                         "Profit:", max(stock_prices[i:]) - stock_prices[i])
        else:
            return i + 1, j + 1
get_max_profit(stock_prices)
```

I expect to get:
 "Buy Price:" 5 "Sell Price:" 14 "Profit:" 9
But I keep getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     line 32, in 
>       get_max_profit(stock_prices)
>     line 20, in get_max_profit
>       if stock_prices[i] == buy:
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Could you take another look at your program's syntax -- `return print...` is not valid Python

Comment: Even after removing print after return, I still get the same error

Comment: I'm not seeing your exact same error but I do see a possible issue with using the same loop variable name as your array -- `for stock_prices in stock_prices`

Comment: @DanielCorin `return print(...)` should be valid. The function will return `None`, the return value of `print`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 you're right. I've been swapping between python 2 and 3 too much lately

Comment: you should use some other iterator for the loop than the variable name, i.e. stock_prices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check this line:

```
for stock_prices in stock_prices
```

and replace it with

```
for stock_price in stock_prices
```

It will resolve your problem,

but I do think there is a problem in your logic as well, so you won't get the expected result.

Here is the improved logic, but I would suggest that you try it yourself first and this must be the last resort:

```
stock_prices = [12, 7, 5, 8, 11, 14]

buy = min(stock_prices)
sell = max(stock_prices)


def get_max_profit(stock_prices):
    i = 0
    j = 1
    for stock_price in stock_prices:
        if stock_prices[i] == buy:
            return print("Buy Price:", stock_prices[i], "Sell Price:", max(stock_prices[i:]),
                         "Profit:", max(stock_prices[i:]) - stock_prices[i])
        elif stock_prices[j] > stock_prices[i] and (stock_prices[i:] != buy and stock_prices[i:] > stock_prices[i]):
            return print("Buy Price:", stock_prices[i], "Sell Price:", max(stock_prices[i:]),
                         "Profit:", max(stock_prices[i:]) - stock_prices[i])
        else:
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1


def app():
    get_max_profit(stock_prices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

**Happy Coding**

Comment: this did work. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the logic? as i did not get any output

Comment: Thank you @Perplexabot ! I am new to stackoverflow as well.